# are attributes without value allowed in HTML4?

Tags: html, html4

I wonder if HTML 4 allows attributes without value, as being equivalent to attributes with an empty value. For example:

```
<h2 section>foobar</h2>
```

instead of:`<h2 section="">foobar</h2>`

Are the two snippets equally valid? If not, are they valid in HTML version 5?

thanks!

Comment: They are equally invalid as `section` is not a [valid attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes)

Comment: Plug it into w3's validator and observe the error messages.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Boolean Attributes, Yes they are completely valid.

[From W3C:](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2) *(On SGML & HTML)*

> Some attributes play the role of boolean variables (e.g., the selected
> attribute for the `OPTION` element). Their appearance in the start tag
> of an element implies that the value of the attribute is "true". Their
> absence implies a value of "false".
>
> Boolean attributes may legally take a single value: the name of the
> attribute itself (e.g., `selected="selected"`).

This states that Boolean attributes are valid in HTML4 as well, but if you use something like, would be invalid.. because that boolean belongs to `option` tag.. Thanks to [@Ronni Skansing](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/14732353#14732353) for clarifying the doubt..

```
<p selected>Hello</p>
```

[image]

---

**HTML5 Docs :**

[From W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-attr-empty) :

**Empty Attribute Syntax**

> Certain attributes may be specified by providing just the attribute
> name, with no value.

---

[From W3C:](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes) *(HTML 5.1 Nightly )*

> A number of attributes are boolean attributes. The presence of a
> boolean attribute on an element represents the true value, and the
> absence of the attribute represents the false value.

---

**BUT**

<s>`section`</s> is an *invalid* attribute, if you want to define your own attributes, HTML5 provides a way to do that.. you need to use [`data-`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) prefix, for example, your <s>`section`</s> should be written as `data-section`, this way your attribute will be counted as *valid*.

---

If you hesitate to do so, we always have a validator to check - [W3C Markup Validation Service](http://validator.w3.org/)

[image]

<sup>^ Validated As HTML5</sup>

---

> **NOTE**: Though I provided `data-` is applicable for HTML5, using custom
> attributes in HTML4 is invalid, no matter even if you define `data-`
> before the attribute name, but, boolean attributes are valid in HTML4
> as well.

Comment: The question asks about HTML 4, but the quote is from an HTML5 draft, and the validation screen shot shows HTML5 validation.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Boolean attributes are valid in HTML4 as well, also, I would like you to read the note at the end of the answer and also this small text below the image which says *Validated As HTML5*, so I don't think downvote is a right thing here :)

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Also, I've stated that **HTML5 provides a way to do that**

Comment: This still does not answer the question asked in the title and the start of text, only (incompletely) a secondary question at the end.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Great, you can post the correct one than :) I won't mind, according to me, the answer covers the point completely..

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Shared the generalize version of the docs as well :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien: I now have that feeling of reading a well-explained, nicely-formatted answer! +1

Answer (score 5):

As formally defined, HTML 4 does not allow attributes without a value. What is commonly regarded as attribute without value, as in `<input checked>`, is formally an attribute value without an attribute name (and an equals sign). Though misleadingly characterized as “boolean attributes” with special minimization rules in HTML 4 specs, those specs normatively cite the SGML standard.

By the SGML standard, whenever an attribute is declared by enumerating keywords that are the only allowed values, an attribute specification may, under certain conditions, be minimized to the value. This means that in HTML 4, the tag `<input checkbox>` is valid; the attribute is a minimized form of `type=checkbox`. No browser supports that (they parse `checkbox` as attribute name), but in validators, the construct passes.

In practice, the part of the attribute minimization rules that browsers support consists of just the special cases where an attribute is declared as allowing a single keyword value only, such as the `checked` attribute, which is formally declared with

```
 <!ATTLIST INPUT checked     (checked)      #IMPLIED>
```

So it depends on how the attribute is declared in the HTML 4 spec.

But this means that the minimized attribute `checked` means `checked=checked`. The value is not empty but the keyword `checked`. On the other hand, browsers treat such attributes as “presence attributes”: what matters is whether an element has that attribute or not, not its value.

In HTML5 serialized as XHTML (i.e., as XML), things are simple: every attribute specification must be of the form name="value" or name='value', so the equals sign is required, and so are the quotation marks; logically, the value is always there, though it can be the empty string, as in `alt=""`.

In HTML5 serialized as HTML, some attributes are defined so that an attribute value (and an equals sign) is not required. Rather confusingly, they are the attributes declared as being “boolean attributes” (it’s confusing e.g. because the values `true` and `false` are *not* allowed, but the name partly reflects the principle that the corresponding DOM property, or “IDL attribute” as they call it, has the truth values `true` and `false` as the only permitted values). For such attributes, by definition, the value is even immaterial; only the presence of the attribute matters. For example, for the `checked` attribute, no value is used, but if a value is given, it must be either the empty string (`checked=""`) or identical with the attribute name, case insensitively (e.g., `checked=Checked`). Any other value is nonconforming but is required to work, with the same meaning (e.g., `checked=false` means the same as `checked`).

Regarding the specific example, it is not valid in any version of HTML, since there is no attribute `section` declared.

Comment: Nice explaination. But how about a attribute such as value="" ? Maybe you could also add a source to the cite "As formally defined, HTML 4 does not allow attributes without a value."

Comment: I will surely delete my answer if I get a link which says *HTML 4 does not allow attributes without a value* though +1 for really detailed answer.

Comment: HTML 4.01 says in conformance requirements (clause 4.1) that HTML documents are SGML documents. SGML is defined by ISO 8879, which defines (in clause 7.9) attribute specification as *(name =)? attribute value specification*, where (...)? indicates omissibility. So it allows the name, not the value to be omitted.

Comment: This is great information, but do all browsers support minimization as per the spec (apart from the enumerated-value format in your `<input checkbox>` example)? It's been very hard to find definitive answers on that.

Answer (score 0):

Both snippets are syntactically valid in html4 and html5. The first is not valid xhtml, because in xhtml an attribute value is required.

On the other hand, section is not a defined attibute, but it is a valid tag in html5. Therefore your code is not valid.