# Angular div tag attribute with no equals

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, attributes

I apologize if this is a duplicate. I see in some people's code, they have something like this:

```
<div ui-grid="myUIGrid" ui-grid-selection ui-grid-resize-columns class="grid" />
```

What is `ui-grid-selection` and `ui-grid-resize-columns`? I've never seen an attribute without an equals sign before. The sample code is using angular. Is it an angular thing?

Comment: Those are boolean attributes. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796217/are-attributes-without-value-allowed-in-html4).

Comment: This is not an angular thing. Your question is answered here
[Are empty data attributes allowed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729080/are-empty-html5-data-attributes-valid)

Comment: Although all of these do happen to be for Angular, and Angular directives leverage it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mentioned attributes are marker attributes for angularJs Grid.

> ui-grid-selection  : Enable grid row selection
>
> ui-grid-resize-columns : Enable column resize

These attributes will take effect after parsing of script.

Simple example of attribute without value is "disable". To disable element in html we can write either disable=disable Or simply "disable"