# HTML attribute not in quotes

Tags: html, css

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-GkMjUZsmM

I am watching a web dev video on youtube and I don't understand this code

```
<body>
<div class="board" id="board">
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
    <div class="cell" data-cell></div>
</div>
```

why is the data-cell not in class or id quotation marks?

Thanks

Comment: It's an attribute. Attributes aren't in quotes. The `class` attribute isn't, either. :)

Comment: For reference, see [Using data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [boolean attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21796245/924299).

Comment: Lest you be misled, `data-cell` is not a boolean attribute. Like all `data-*` attributes, it's a string attribute. Here, its value in the empty string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you quote HTML5 attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495310/do-you-quote-html5-attributes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Reasons why the code didn't work

1. He's probably using a code editor that knows what it's trying to do.
2. It is an attribute. Learn more about them [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

#### Possible solutions

if you're wanting to create a tic-tac-toe game, you could:

- Follow a more simple tutorial (on dev.to).. I've already got you one [here](https://dev.to/bornasepic/pure-and-simple-tic-tac-toe-with-javascript-4pgn)
- Possibly watch a new tutorial from him or someone else.

If you **do not recommend** any of these solutions, **I can find more solutions** to help you with ur request.